# How can I pass down slots to a grandchild component in Vue 3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

If I have a `layout` component that contains a few slots, is it possible to have a component within `layout` populate those slots?

[**JS Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/tmjnb1po/)

```html
<div id="app">
    <layout>
        <page></page>
    </layout>
</div>
```

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({});

app.component('layout', {
    template: `
        <header>
            <slot name="header"></slot>
        </header>

        <main>
            <slot name="main"></slot>
        </main>
    `,
});

app.component('page', {
    template: `
        <!--
            is there a way fill each slot of "layout"? i.e.
            
            <template #header>
                <h1>Page Header</h1>
            </template>
            
            <template #main>
                <h1>Page Content</h1>
            </template>
        -->
    `,
});

app.mount('#app');
```

Comment: do you want to drill down the slots?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim Hi Brahim, that sounds like the right way of saying it. I've tried a few suggestions from Github issues ([for example](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/pull/7765#issuecomment-450423632)), but nothing works so far.

Comment: Ok, let me understand your use case and i hope that i could find a solution

Comment: i think i misunderstood you, do you want to expose the slots of page to be used as layout slots?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim The other way around, I would like the slots defined in `layout` to be filled from `page`. I'm beginning to realise it might not be possible without a render function. My use case isn't critical, so I'll find another solution. I'll leave the question open for any future answers.

Comment: After thinking and debugging i think it's not possible, you could for example pass slot from parent to the child `A--->B--->C` in this example you could pass slots from B to C using loop like `<template v-for="slot in Object.keys($slots)" v-slot:[slot]="scope"> <slot :name="slot" v-bind="scope"/></template>` as i did one of my components, but your case seems not possible

Comment: do you want to follow the pattern used in nuxtjs?

Comment: Thanks Brahim. I'm going to have my `page` components import which ever `layout` they need and start from there, it looks like Nuxt has a similar technique.

Comment: It's my pleasure,  in nuxt the layout represents the main page and inside it there's one part that changes which represented by `<Nuxt/>`, in your case the slot named main represents that https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-3-ts-forked-zjne5?file=/src/App.vue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems what I'm looking for is being referred to as `template blocks` in other places. This is not something Evan You (the creator of Vue) currently supports as he doesn't believe this functionality adds enough value for the added complexity.

**Some interesting links:**

- [Template blocks for component inheritence](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/5401) ([proposed syntax](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/5401#issuecomment-400957542))
- [Possible upcoming third-party package to achieve this](https://github.com/anthonygore/vue-template-extension-loader/issues/1)
- [Example of using Pug with it's concepts of `block` and `extends`](https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2020/02/24/extending-vuejs-components-templates/)